# Error with TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

This code doesn't even output anything and I don't know what's wrong with it...

Code:

```
message.guild.roles.cache.filter(r => r.deletable).forEach(r => { 
  r.delete(); 
  console.info(`deleted ${r.name} ID: ${r.id}`)
});
```

Comment: Read the error message. `Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined` means that `message.guild.roles.cache` does not have a value. Try to take this further and see which property does not have a value. We need more information to give a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

Like garrifra said `message.guild.roles.cache` is undefined, this is probably because you aren't on v12 discord.js, so either update or change it to just `message.guild.roles`:

```js
message.guild.roles.forEach(r => { 
  r.delete()
    .then(() => console.log(`deleted ${r.name} ID: ${r.id}`))
    .catch(() => console.log(`Failed to delete ${r.name} | ${r.id}`)); 
});
```

Comment: That gives me another error: TypeError: (intermediate value).forEach is not a function I've tried searching up what would be the cause but i just can't seem to find a solution. I know how to make it work but then it'll give me more errors of discord api saying invalid role etc but that's because the roles are undeletable (upper to the one's the bot can delete) that's why i added that in but it doesn't seem to work at all after that or just returns nothing. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Try logging what `message.guild.roles` is then, and add the result to your post, also update the code to your post. > I know how to make it work, how exactly? You might need to just add a catch statement when you call delete instead, I've looked over v11 and v12 docs and I can't find `<Role>.deletable`

Comment: This would be the proper code but you'd get warnings whenever a role is above the bot or it has no permissions to delete it code: message.guild.roles.forEach(r => {
        r.delete();
console.info(`deleted ${r.name} ID: ${r.id}`)     it works but it's not viable for the warnings

Comment: Like i said you would need a catch statement, edited the post

Comment: Thanks, i didn't think of that myself